# Web scraping problem : Data does not show when printed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So i tried to scrape this website: https://top-1000-sekolah.ltmpt.ac.id/site/page?id=2001
if you inspect element, there's a div with id of tab-1, tab-2,tab-3, tab-4 . So I tried ti scrape each id but somehow only tab-1 data's were grabbed. so what did I do wrong??

```
pk = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@id='tab-1'])")
pbm = driver.find_element_by_id('tab-2')
pu = driver.find_element_by_id('tab-3')
ppu = driver.find_element_by_id('tab-4')
```

The output I expect from tab-2 is :

```
Kemampuan Kuantitatif
2
Urut Nasional
1
Urut Provinsi
Rerata
640,253
Nilai Tertinggi
721,15
Nilai Terendah
511,14
Standar Deviasi
44,1
```

and currently tab-2 output is blank( ' ' )

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Use print(pbm.get_attribute('textContent')) to get all child element texts.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```py
pbm = driver.find_element_by_id('tab-2')
print(pbm.text)
```

If that doesn't work, I suspect it is because that div class with the id of `tab-2` has many child elements. You will need to select those individual child elements directly to get the data you need. Use the XPATH method which you used up top.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 details order-2 order-lg-1">
        <h3 align="center">
            Kemampuan Memahami Bacaan dan Menulis
        </h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="count-box">
                    <i class="icofont-award"></i>
                    <span data-toggle="counter-up">5</span>
                    <p>Urut Nasional</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="count-box">
                    <i class="icofont-award"></i>
                    <span data-toggle="counter-up">1</span>
                    <p>Urut Provinsi</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header" align="center">Rerata</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title" align="center"><b>589,104</b></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header" align="center">Nilai Tertinggi</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title" align="center"><b>709,61</b></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header" align="center">Nilai Terendah</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title" align="center"><b>371,88</b></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header" align="center">Standar Deviasi</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title" align="center"><b>65,96</b></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example to parse the name `Kemampuan Kuantitatif`,

```py
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab-2"]/div/div/h3')
print(name)
```

Comment: it doesnt work, it gave me a blank output if the id != tab-1